# My variable loginSuccesful Changes automatically

Tags: java

I am trying to create a login screen and am using the `ASyncTask` Class. I use it to check if the username and password are available in the server. And the task returns success. I then use that to change the value of the variable `loginSuccessfull` to 'true' and it changes as i check it with logd. But when I use it to check in the if statement the value automatically changes to the earlier one which is false. why is that?

```
public class LoginScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText usernameEditText;
    EditText passwordEditText;
    Button loginButton;
    public static final String TAG = "LoginScreenActivity";
    protected boolean loginSuccessful = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);
        usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.username_edit_text);
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password_edit_text);
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        final Toast wrongCredentials = Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        final LoginScreenBackground background = new LoginScreenBackground();


        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                background.execute(usernameEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + loginSuccessful);

                if(loginSuccessful){
                    showDeliveryScreen();
                }
                else{
                   wrongCredentials.show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    class LoginScreenBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String loginURLString = "http://localhost/login.php";
        boolean loginSuccess = false;
        public static final String TAG = "BackgroudActivity";

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + s);
            if(s.equals("success")){
                loginSuccessful = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + loginSuccessful);
            }

            //Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + this.loginSuccess);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String responseFromServer = "";
            String username = strings[0];
            String password = strings[1];

            try{
                //Setting up the http connection
                URL url = new URL(loginURLString);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

                //Setting up the output stream to the php file on the server
                OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));

                //setting up the data need to be sent to the server
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

                //Send data throught the buffered reader
                bufferedWriter.write(data);

                //close connections
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                //Setting up the input stream from the php file on th server
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = "";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    responseFromServer += line;
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + responseFromServer);


            }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.getMessage();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.getMessage();
            }



            return responseFromServer;

        }
    }

    public void showDeliveryScreen(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DriverDeliveryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

`true` is expected but the result shown is `false`.

Comment: does it print the log?  Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + loginSuccessful);

Comment: Which is printed earlier: `Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + loginSuccessful);` or `Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + loginSuccessful);`?

Comment: This is what prints `onPostExecute: success` `onPostExecute: true`

Answer (score 0):

Actually thats not the case its just an optical illusion to you, In your `OnPostExecute` your are not getting success response.
As you have 2 logs with same key in `OnPostExecute`

```
Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + s);
```

And

```
Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + loginSuccessful);
```

thats why you might be thinking that `loginSuccessfull` variable value is set to `true`, but in actual its not the case.

Comment: S.Lion, does it solve your problem or u need any other help?